# Is it possible to form a neighbourhood of $x$ by taking points only from the sequences $\{x_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose in a metric space $X$ I consider all the sequences $\{x_n\}$ which converge to $x$. Is it possible to form a neighbourhood of $x$ by taking points only from the sequences $\{x_n\}$ ?

For each sequence $\{x_n\}$, I get a $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$ we can make the difference of $x_n$ and $x$ arbitrary small. Now suppose I have to form a neighbourhood of $x$ of radius $\delta$. So, for each sequence I choose $N_\delta$ and then take all the points from $\{x_n\}$ such that $n > N_\delta$ for each sequence. Now, I claim that union of all the points is the neighbourhood of radius $\delta$ of point $x$. Is this correct ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading the problem wrong, but isn't every single point of $X$ in *some* sequence converging to $x$? (no matter which $x$)

Answer (score 4):

Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ and let $y\in U$. The sequence $(y,x,x,x,\ldots)$ converges to $x$ and so you can pick $y$ from this sequence.

Comment: Now, if presenjit did not mean this, he should edit the question to show what he did mean.

Comment: @GEdgar: I edited. Looks like trivial. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: @prasenjit: It is trivial, but your argument seems bungled.  Did you read Daniel's answer?

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space, the topology can be reconstructed from knowledge of all converging sequences, if that's what you're asking. However, as @I.J.Kennedy mentioned (and similarly to @DanielRust's answer), for all $y\in X$ the sequence $(y,x,x,\ldots,x,\ldots)$ converges to $x$ (so reconstructing the topology isn't as straightforward as taking members of such sequences).